# Installing python-rosdep manually is required to follow the official instruction on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to this change (https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/pull/731), it seems like `python-rosdep` is not required by `ros-melodic-rospack` and not installed by just executing `apt install ros-melodic-ros-base`.

Is it necessary to manually install `python-rosdep` when installing ROS on a new computer to follow the [official instruction](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu)?

I wrote a detailed log on this issue (https://github.com/Tiryoh/ros_setup_scripts_ubuntu/issues/1).

If there is a better place to write an issue about this problem, please direct me.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347319/installing-python-rosdep-manually-is-required-to-follow-the-official-instruction-on-ubuntu-18.04?/) by [tiryoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/52782/tiryoh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2020-03-23

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [IanCol](https://answers.ros.org/users/26764/iancol/) on 2020-03-23**:
I've also came across this bug because my CI testing for melodic is now failing, the official install instructions are now broken.
http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu

**Comment by [tiryoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/52782/tiryoh/) on 2020-03-24**:
I have reported the details on this issue.
https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/745

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosdep` has been an optional package.  Executing `apt install python-rosdep` is required from now on.

https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdep/issues/745#issuecomment-604065699

http://wiki.ros.org/action/info/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu?action=diff&rev2=7&rev1=6

---

Originally posted by [tiryoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/52782/tiryoh/) with karma: 41 on 2020-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1